# Passing file data between Administration app and Web site app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services

We have two separate web applications for a site:  One for the site itself, and one for the cms/administration side.  I'm not sure why the original developer designed it this way, but whatever.

I am tasked with adding some functionality to the administration side that uploads files.  These files then need to exist within the folder structure of the actual site.  I was thinking I might have to write a web service that sits on the actual site that accepts the file bytes and file name from a call within the administration site, and creates the file in the correct folder, but I was wondering if anyone had any ideas about a cleaner way to accomplish the same thing.

In general, how would you tackle a scenario where you upload a file on one site, and send it to the directory structure in another?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up going with is to store the full file path to the other site in the web.config.  It's not the most elegant solution, but it works and I'm mildly happy with it since it is easily maintainable across dev/staging/production.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to transfer the uploaded files from one folder to another.

After a file is uploaded on the admin site, the windows service moves the file over to the correct location on the other site. You just need to decide how to communicate with the service - you could add details about the uploaded file to a message queue that the service monitors or perhaps you windows service might just watch the upload folder for any new files.

Comment: I prefer to avoid using windows services, as it adds an unnecessary project into the mix.